# Proyecto OBD + Bluetooth + RasberryPi 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, bluetooth

Estoy trabajando con el OBD y Raspberry, con conexión bluetooth y me sale este error en el código:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "bluepi.py", line 14, in <module>
>     profiles = [ SERIAL_PORT_PROFILE ])
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bluetooth/bluez.py", line 176, in advertise_service
>     raise BluetoothError (str (e))
> bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError: (13, 'Permission denied')
> ```

La librería que descargué fue `pybluez`

¿Alguien tendrà alguna sugerencia que puedo hacer en este caso?

Comment: Hola Ralf bienvenido a [es.so], mirate esta respuesta del sitio en inglés a ver si te orienta https://stackoverflow.com/a/42306883/7131499

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda